# Should I store my data in Umbraco or a bespoke data layer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, umbraco

I'm having a crisis here before starting a (potentially) large project, I use Umbraco alot and because it's so diverse you can pretty much do anything you like with it, but my question is whether to use Umbraco solely as my content *and* data-provider, or whether to create my own ORM (i.e. EF) layer to store the *details* shall we say.

What I'm asking is, is there a line to be drawn, how do you decide when to use a bespoke data-layer?  Is it when you max out the CMS (if possible) or does it depend on the data structure itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my simple rule of thumb:

**If your data is going to be shared out to multiple websites**, consider storing it in a separate database and instead of accessing it directly with and ORM, use a webservice. [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792.aspx) or the [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) offer great ways to perform CRUD operations on the data.

**If the data is only available in you Umbraco site**, keep it in Umbraco. In fact, if you want it to be editable by the user, use Umbraco's document types to capture and store the data. You don't have to let those nodes be navigable directly, you can reference the information from other nodes using Umbraco's [API](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/).

Even if you are sharing the data with other sites, keeping the data in Umbraco may be best as it will allow you to easily collect the data from the user without having to build custom forms and you can still develop webservices to share out the data, using Umbraco's [/Base](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Api/Base/Index) methods or again [WCF](http://optimisticcoder.com/blogs/injecting-restful-wcf-services-into-umbraco-for-jquery-ajax.aspx) or [Web API](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/WebApi/). As a bonus, **newer versions of Umbraco come with built-in [services](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Management-v6/Services/)**.